# Keep api key secure in hosted javascript app

Tags: javascript, api, authorization

I am developing a very lightweight web app based on the esri javascript api for my own learning/"fun".

I have an api key limited in scope and functionality to a single (routing) location service. The app will just draw a route between 2 user selected points.

I am comfortable that I can keep that api key secret and call it from my app when deployed locally, but I don't understand best practice and options should I wish to deploy that application to a server if I wish the key to be secure.

As I understand it the hosted application would need to call that api key from an external (to app code tree) source, but not expose the value of the key to clients utilising the app. How is this best achieved and in what tools? Do I need to write a server based script that returns that key value? Is there a very obvious choice here?

Thanks

I am unaware of the merits of various authorisation options - it may well be there are superior options for achieving the same result.

Comment: Code that runs on the server isn't exposed to users of the application.

Comment: thanks - first one is a bit advanced for where I am I think, my question seems much more basic. I understand server code not being exposed to the application but I want application to retrieve key from server securely if thats possible. Ithink answer below will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong in understanding your question.
However I've hosted a web application on heroku which was using an API key.
So the best practice is to store API Secret KEY, JWT token etc in a .env file.

Create a .env file in the project root and save key like :
`API_KEY=XXXXXXXX`
then you can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm module to load the key from environment file.
Make sure that .env is excluded from tracking in git by adding it in .gitignore

Once the local branch is working perfectly and local server is up and running. If you want to make your project opensource, upload it on github, but for hosting it on any hosting service like heroku you also need to push your .env file as well.

So either you can make a final commit in local repository and add .env file or you can upload .env file in project root using the hosting service of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I dont quite follow the distinction between GitHub hosting and Heroku hosting. I understand the concept of storing the key in a dot.env file - but surely the .env file needs to be alongside the app wherever that is - so it would need uploading to github if I host there?

Comment: See, github only provides static website hosting not server side. People generally make their application opensource so they upload it on github. That's what I was trying to say that if you want others to see your code then make a github reposiroty without pushing the env file and specify in the readme for how to use it. But hosting service keeps code private so you have to upload your env file there.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand - sorry I missed that distinction